# cov(X,XY)? if X,Y is not independent

Tags: correlation, covariance

For two normal random variables , $X$ and $Y$ whose mean are not zero,

If 
$ cov(X,Y) $ is given as $\sigma_{XY}^2  $ ,
are there any simple way to calculate
$ cov(X,XY) ?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us see...
$$\begin{align}
\mathsf{Cov}(X,XY) ~=~& \mathsf E(X^2Y)-\mathsf E(X)~\mathsf E(XY)
\\ ~=~& \mathsf E(X^2Y)-\mathsf E(X)~\big(\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y)+\mathsf E(X)~\mathsf E(Y)\big)
\\ ~=~& \mathsf E(X^2Y)-\mathsf E(X)~\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y)-\mathsf E(X)^2~\mathsf E(Y)
\\ ~=~&  \mathsf E(X^2Y)-\mu_{\small X}~\sigma_{\small XY}^{~2}-\mu_{\small X}^{~2}~\mu_{\small Y}
\end{align}$$
Uhm, ... no.  That's about as simple as it gets.  If you have the means and covariance of $X$ and $Y$, then you will still need to evaluate the expectation of $X^2Y$.